# Get a Force Close due to unknown Reason, Error Log is shown below:

Tags: android

> ```
> 11-10 12:07:00.327: WARN/dalvikvm(558): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
> 11-10 12:07:00.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(558): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 11-10 12:07:00.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(558): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
> ```
>
> ComponentInfo{com.mutmonix.series/com.mutmonix.series.Main}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mutmonix.series.Main in loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.mutmonix.series-1.apk]
>       11-10 12:07:00.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(558):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
>       11-10 12:07:00.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(558):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>       11-10 12:07:00.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(558):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
>       11-10 12:07:00.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(558):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>       11-10 12:07:00.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(558):
>
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 11-10
>   12:07:00.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(558):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 11-10 12:07:00.357:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(558):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 11-10
>   12:07:00.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(558):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 11-10
>   12:07:00.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(558):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 11-10 12:07:00.357:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(558):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   11-10 12:07:00.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(558):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 11-10
>   12:07:00.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(558):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 11-10 12:07:00.357:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(558): Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mutmonix.series.Main in loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.mutmonix.series-1.apk]
>   11-10 12:07:00.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(558):     at
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
>   11-10 12:07:00.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(558):     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573) 11-10
>   12:07:00.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(558):     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532) 11-10
>   12:07:00.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(558):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
>   11-10 12:07:00.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(558):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
>   11-10 12:07:00.357: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(558):     ... 11 more 11-10
>   12:07:00.377: WARN/ActivityManager(68):   Force finishing activity
>   com.mutmonix.series/.Main 11-10 12:07:00.897:
>   WARN/ActivityManager(68): Activity pause timeout for
>   HistoryRecord{45027410 com.mutmonix.series/.Main}

```
Main. Java
package com.mutmonix.series.activities;    
import com.mutmonix.series.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);   
     findViewById(R.id.link_BlueStone).setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId()==R.id.link_BlueStone){

        }

    }




}
```

Manifest File contains the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mutmonix.series" android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Main" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: -1 for: That is not a question at all! No code example where the error occurs, no description what your problem is...

Comment: have you decalred in manifest?

Comment: yes, of course, i can send you my application in winzip, its simplest one, you can review it.

Comment: Can you please show us the full manifest here..? Please don't paste in comments, edit you question and include the manifest code there.

Comment: @Mudassir plz see the Question again, its updated!!!

Comment: Now what you can do is check whether the class `Main` actually resides in the package `com.mutmonix.series`. Please check it.

Answer (score 2):

The reason looks fairly clear to me:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mutmonix.series.Main

It appears that you haven't included that class in your APK. Even if you think you have, you should double check.

Comment: @pakshaheen: What do you mean by "as well"? How exactly have you included it? Clearly the classloader can't load it... Out of interest, do you have two classes with the same name which differ only in case? That might be a problem if you're running in Windows...

Comment: I have exactly included it as er my knowledge and learning,No, I have not two classes with same name in my application,

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you have included Main class in that, then You mus check in

> AndroidManifest.xml

That com.mutmonix.series.Main class included with the correct package name.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

> **package=" com.mutmonix.series"**

```
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".Main" >
```

Comment: You can see here I have included these as well:

 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
  <activity android:name=".Main" android:label="@string/app_name">
   <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
  </activity>

 </application>
</manifest>

Comment: Please check you have mention PACKAGE name in android.